# Simultaneous keypress causing unwanted behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I am making a shooter game with action script 3. I have a hero which moves when any of the arrow key is pressed
my code is as following

```
//some class level variables
private var vx :int = 0;
private var vy :int = 0;

//in the Main constructor
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , moveHero);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , stopHero);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnter);

//and all the handlers
function moveHero(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 37)
    {
        vx = -5;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 38)
    {
        vy = -10;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 39)
    {
        vx = 5;
    } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 40)
    {
        vy = 10;
    }
}
function stopHero(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    //when key is up stop miving the hero
    vx = 0;
    vy = 0;
}
function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
    //updtae hero position 
    hero.x += vx;
    hero.y += vy;
}
```

Now my problem is when user have both up and down keys or left and right keys under his fingers and suddenly press them alternately then the hero shows a notable lag in making response to the key presses

Comment: the key presses should set booleans and in your enterframe listener you should move the character according to those boolean. The action itself should not happen in the keypress handler.

Comment: @BotMaster Why the OP needs an enterframe listener ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do exactly like **BotMaster** said in the comments, and here's how it looks like in AS3 code:

```
var keys:Array = new Array(255);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , keyUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , loop);

function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}

function loop(e:Event):void {
    if(keys[Keyboard.LEFT]) {
        trace("Moving left...");
    } else if(keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
        trace("Moving right...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why we need `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP` and `Event.ENTER_FRAME` ?

Comment: @akmozo `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP` set states in our `keys` array which we later query in our main loop for whether a key is down or not.

Comment: I understand what you do, but why we need a loop using Event.ENTER_FRAME when just KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN can do the job ?

Comment: Well since we're talking game dev, let me enlighten you of the most important structure element of any game - **The main loop**. This is where all your logic happens, where you update sub-systems, and render graphics on the screen. Keyboard is just another utility which should provide feedback to the game-logic system. If you're going to start putting game logic inside the Keyboard handlers, well you're asking for trouble.